# Loading a pretrained model using torch.load gives "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transformers_modules"

Tags: python, torch

The following is the code:

```
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, AutoModel
import torch

model = torch.load("./tmp/gptj.pt")
model.eval()

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("./tmp")
device = "cpu"
inputs = tokenizer.encode("function helloWorld():", return_tensors="pt").to(device)
outputs = model.generate(inputs)
print(tokenizer.decode(outputs[0]))type here
```

The environment is:

Python : 3.9.15
torch : 2.0.0
transformers : 4.28.1

I have tried changing the versions of torch and transformers but to no avail.

Full error trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anand.keshavan@postman.com/bigcode_santacoder_model/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 218, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/anand.keshavan@postman.com/bigcode_santacoder_model/app.py", line 5, in <module>
    from query import exec_query
  File "/Users/anand.keshavan@postman.com/bigcode_santacoder_model/query.py", line 4, in <module>
    model = torch.load("/Users/anand.keshavan@postman.com/bigcode_santacoder_model/tmp/gptj.pt")
  File "/Users/anand.keshavan@postman.com/bigcode_santacoder_model/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 809, in load
    return _load(opened_zipfile, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "/Users/anand.keshavan@postman.com/bigcode_santacoder_model/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 1172, in _load
    result = unpickler.load()
  File "/Users/anand.keshavan@postman.com/bigcode_santacoder_model/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 1165, in find_class
    return super().find_class(mod_name, name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transformers_modules'
```

Code used to save the model:

```js
import os
import shutil 
import tarfile
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM
 

model_save_dir="./tmp"
 
 
key_prefix="gpt-j"
 

os.makedirs(model_save_dir,exist_ok=True)
 

print("Loading model...")



model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("bigcode/santacoder", trust_remote_code=True)

print('Saving model...')
torch.save(model, os.path.join(model_save_dir,"gptj.pt"))

print("Loading tokeninzer...")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bigcode/santacoder')
print("saving tokenizer..."")
tokenizer.save_pretrained(model_save_dir)
```

Comment: Can you please share the full error stack? And maybe also some details on how you have saved the model in the first place.

Comment: Added the the detailed error trace and the code used to save the model

Comment: My guess is that `dill` was installed in the env used to save the module. When this is the case, torch can use `dill`, instead of `pickle` for the serialization. Now you are trying to load that model using the standard `pickle`. Can you try installing `dill` in your env and see if it solves the issue?

Comment: Tried with dill installed. Still the same error.

Comment: Can you get a `pip freeze` of the original env and the one you are working on to see if there are other differences?

Comment: They are the same. I am working in the same environment for saving and loading

Comment: Okay, I solved the problem by using "model.save_pretrained" instead of torch.save